# "Was selected" - an action or a status?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

CONTEXT: Tracking when a user selected values on a computer program.

The word "on" has to be used differently to portray **action** ("was turned on") vs **status** ("was on"). But a problem occurs when applying this to the word "selected": "became selected" portrays action, but the phrase "was selected" seems ambiguous.

For example, the sentence "We know that that option was selected on Tuesday" could mean 2 things:

1. An action was performed on Tuesday to select that option.
2. All throughout Tuesday, that option was selected, and so it must have become selected BEFORE Tuesday.

Is there another succinct way to describe option 2, since "was selected" is ambiguous?

Thanks!

Comment: "That was the selected option" may be the closest to the original.

Comment: I don't quite follow your second paragraph. You say that "was turned on" indicates only action, but it can also represent the status of something: "When I walked into the room, the light was [[already]] turned on."

Comment: Get used to ambiguity. You normally can't tell a passive from a predicate adjective without adding bells and whistles to distinguish them. That's just the way it is, and different people can have different individual grammars that tell them it's one or the other. In fact, it almost never matters, except to OCD teachers.

Comment: Why not 'The choice had been made by Tuesday' or 'Come Tuesday, the option had been selected.'?

Comment: Context usually disambiguates it, so it's not generally a concern.

Comment: Can you clarify how 'a user selected values on a computer program' sits with the very different uses in portraying action ("was turned on") vs status ("was on")'?

Either way, what programming language is used here, and how does its grammar relate to English?